# What is the best way to add a text field to a form select in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails 4 I have a form select with three options, one of which is called 'other' where I want to display a text field and have the input sent to server as the form value.

```
.field
    = f.label :answer, 'Please select..'
    = f.select :answer, ['option a','option b','other...'], prompt: 'Select One'
    #other
     .other
      = f.text_field :answer
```

model.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  other = $('#other').html()
  $('.other').remove()
  if $('#mymodel_answer :selected').text() == 'other...'
    $('#other').html(other)
  $('#mymodel_answer').change ->
    if $('#mymodel_answer :selected').text() == 'other...'
      $('#other').html(other)
    if $('#mymodel_answer :selected').text() != 'other...'
      $('.other').remove()
```

this works but feels a little hacky, what other ways are there to do this?

Comment: Hope you are doing great. I am trying with same concept but not getting the desired results.

Comment: If interested please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399104/select-others-option-from-drop-down-list-creating-text-field-ruby-on-rails-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled form elements are not submitted so you could just add a bit of CSS to hide disabled things:

```
input[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

Then use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to enable/disable the extra input as things change. So given some HTML like this:

```
<form>
    <select name="s" id="s">
        <option value="show">With extra thing</option>
        <option value="hide">No extra thing</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="t" name="t" placeholder="extra thing...">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

you could say:

```
$('#s').change ->
    disabled = $(@).val() == 'hide'
    $('#t').prop('disabled', disabled)
```

to show-enabled/hide-disable the `<input type="text">` as the `<select>` changes.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LmAMR/

If you didn't want to use CSS to hide disabled elements then you'd just need to throw in appropriate [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) calls:

```
$('#s').change ->
    disabled = $(@).val() == 'hide'
    fn       = if disabled then 'hide' else 'show'
    $('#t')[fn]().prop('disabled', disabled)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/F8Dqn/