# Select 'OTHERS' option from drop down list creating text field Ruby on Rails - 4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

_form.html.erb

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.select(:description, options_for_select([['', ''],['METRO', 'METRO'], ['BUS', 'BUS'], ['TAXI', 'TAXI'], ['OTHERS', 'OTHERS']]), {}, {class: "form-control", id: "expense_description"}) %>
  <br>
  <div id="otherDesc">
    <%= f.text_field :description_other, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @expenses.each do |expense| %>

<tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

<td class="col-1"><%= (expense.description_other.present? ? expense.description_other : expense.description) %></td>

</tr>

<% end %>
```

expenses_controller.rb

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_expense, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /expenses
  # GET /expenses.json
  def index
    @expenses = Expense.all
  end

  # GET /expenses/1
  # GET /expenses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /expenses/new

   def new
    if Expense.last.present?
      @expense = Expense.last.dup
    else
      @expense = Expense.new
    end
   end

  # GET /expenses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /expenses
  # POST /expenses.json
  def create
    @expense = Expense.new(expense_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @expense.save
        format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Expense was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @expense }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /expenses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /expenses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @expense.update(expense_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Expense was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @expense }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /expenses/1
  # DELETE /expenses/1.json
  def destroy
    @expense.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to expenses_url, notice: 'Expense was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_expense
      @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def expense_params
      params.require(:expense).permit(:description, :description_other)
    end
end
```

expense.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#expense_description').on('change',function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        selectedValue == "OTHERS" ? $("#otherDesc").show() : $("#otherDesc").hide()
      });
 });
```

general.scss

```
#otherDesc {
display:none;
}
```

Everything works fine except my index page where I get two values for 'OTHERS' selected option as OTHERS + MY OWN DESCRIPTION. For example in the image it is OTHERS WHITE GLUE. But I would like to have only WHITE GLUE as the description.

Please find attached the image for your reference.[image: Picture1.jpg]

I have tried too hard but unable to get the desired result.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This one should be easy to adapt ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291645/add-input-fields-in-form-when-dropdown-option-selected if you need more details you just goto the Jquery documentation page.

Comment: Per convo in chat - here's a question that demonstrates how to add fields to a form - the code in here goes inside the code that 'triggers' off the 'anchor' in the previous link I gave you ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099301/dynamically-adding-html-form-field-using-jquery

Comment: Here's a helpful tutorial that will walk you through the theory (its wrong version but tells you how to go about the process).  You will have to write your own condition to test. https://rubyplus.com/articles/4211-Using-Ajax-and-jQuery-in-Rails-5-Apps

Comment: What happens if you wrap `<td class="col-1"><%= expense.description %>&nbsp` in a conditional so it doesn't display if `<%= link_to expense.description_other,{}, {:style => 'color: #CC3366'} %>` is displayed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried with my conditionals it is not working. If you would like any suggestions please proceed with your conditionals.Wait for your reply.

Comment: Help me a bit since I can't see how it's not working - what does it display when the conditionals don't work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It displays 'OTHERS' option from the select menu + my own description such as "OTHERS COURIER". I would like to exclude OTHERS and show only the COURIER as the description. Wait for your reply.

Comment: I'm guess it's just the label like you are spitting out an object id...but just to be sure go into rails console or check your  log files...

Comment: If you have logging on (tail -f log/development.log should show) grab the development.log file and copy the part where it calls the variable from the db.

Comment: yaseen@ubuntu:~/Desktop/expense_app$ tail -f log/development.log
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/expenses/11
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)


Started GET "/expenses/11" for ::1 at 2017-09-28 23:24:15 +0400
Processing by ExpensesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  Expense Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses" WHERE "expenses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  Rendered expenses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 42.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155548/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-mirv).

Comment: I'm wrapped up with move, 3 offline projects & my own research - really sorry - I feel like you're close, but this is a 92% done for 8% of the work & 8% of the work (making it look pretty) taking 92%.

Comment: How about this one?

Comment: I added up the controller, hope you have almost all the code needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - I'm kind of blind sometimes...

```
index.html.erb
<td class="col-1"><%= expense.description %>&nbsp;<%= link_to expense.description_other,{}, {:style => 'color: #CC3366'} %></td>
```

You've got two `<%= ... %>`'s in there ...

`<%= expense.description %>`

And then

`<%= link_to expense.description_other,{}, {:style => 'color: #CC3366'} %>`

Get ride of the first one when `OTHER` is selected, using an if conditional(the trinary operator we talked about `<expression> ? <if true do this happens>: <if false this happens>`  The conditional would have to contain both statements inside one `<%= ... %>` block.

Also, you have an issue here ... should have a conditional of some sort  ... probably the `||=` & drop the Expense.new or the Expense.last.dup

```
  def new
    @expense = Expense.new

    @expense =  Expense.last.dup
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding this,<expression> ? <if true do this happens>: <if false this happens> I tried and I have , <%= (Expense.last.present? ? expense.description : expense.description_other) %> But one problem it shows only 'OTHERS' as the description.

Comment: I updated the /expenses/new in the controller and now it is working fine.

Comment: Awesome, if that works now, you could select the answer on the question & start a new one for further questions.

Comment: I go for this, <% if expense.description && expense.description_other %>
      <td class="col-1"><%= expense.description.sub('OTHERS','') %>&nbsp;<%= link_to expense.description_other,{}, {:style => 'color: #CC3366'} %></td>
      <% end %> and it works just after I used the .sub  method.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that, have you gone into rails console & done the @expense.description tests I talked about the other week?

If it's not fix I posted here ... it's probably the serialization of the hash.

Comment: In rails console I did  e=Expense.last and then e.description finally I got => "OTHERS"

Comment: I have two text fields in rails form, when I select 'OTHERS' and fill that field then it takes this 'OTHERS' value as well as the description_other's value, that is why I don't get single value with this expression as mentioned, <%= (Expense.last.present? ? expense.description : expense.description_other) %>

Comment: Using that formatting idea you should be able to do it without the `.sub`, you just have to take it to the next step of filling it from the controller into the view properly.  It's not the end of the world, but it is something you should know how to do.  There is a combination of if statements that will get it for you, but based on the what I'm seeing I'm not sure what they are...

Comment: You mean what I did for the new action in the controller, in the same way do I have to make a logic for this to be working without using .sub

Comment: Yes, as I keep saying - I can't see it - but most likely reasons are ...  First, the view doesn't have the right combination of if statements or `<something> ? <if true> : <if false>`.  Second, the information being fed in by the controller, maybe from the model has the word "OTHER" in it & the controller isn't setup to give just the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156359/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-mirv).

Comment: No, you never even posted the rails console output I asked for to test for the other option ... I was just letting you know there is a better way to structure your application that will save you the trouble in your next attempt & you need to go read the tutorial I linked you to get a better understanding of using MVC.

Comment: Rails Console Output :2.2.0 :001 > Expense.last
  Expense Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses"  ORDER BY "expenses"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Expense id: 41, description: "OTHERS", description_other: "Carrefour", created_at: "2017-10-10 18:51:39", updated_at: "2017-10-10 18:51:39">

Comment: If it works for you!  Earlier I was just commenting the .sub is not standard - it's often a time balancing act - what's important at that point :)